# pandas group by non zero average percentage across country

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'Country':['UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India','India'],
    'Product':['A','A','A','A','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D','D','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A','A'],
            'ID': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5], 
       'val': [0,4,3,1,5,5,0,5,6,7,8,9,10,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,0,0,7,8,9]
    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Country','Product','ID', 'val'])

print(df2)
```

[image]

I wanted to find out country wise and Product availability average percentage i.e(count of non zero/null ID/total ID values).

India Product A has 3 Non Zero values across all IDs 8 under India.so percentage will be (3/8= 38%)

Product B don't have any nonzero/null values so 100%

final Average for India will be (38+100)/2  = 69%

[image]

I have tried to get the count of all id's but i didnt able to get the non zero values in group by

```
df1 = df2.groupby(['Country','Product'])['ID'].agg(['size']).reset_index()

df1['id_count'] = df1.groupby(['Country'])['size'].transform('max')
```

How to get the non zero id's count in group by?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try converting your logic to code:

```
# count the non-zero value per country/product
prods = df2['val'].ne(0).groupby([df2['Country'],df2['Product']]).sum()

# count the number of products per country
ids = df2.groupby('Country')['ID'].nunique()

out = prods.div(ids).unstack().assign(Average=lambda x: x.mean(1))
```

Or you can chain them:

```
output = (df2['val'].ne(0)
            .groupby([df2['Country'],df2['Product']]).sum()
            .div(df2.groupby('Country')['ID'].nunique())
            .unstack()
            .assign(Average=lambda x: x.mean(1))
         )
```

Output

```
Product      A    B         C    D   Average
Country                                     
India    0.375  1.0       NaN  NaN  0.687500
UK       0.500  NaN  0.333333  1.0  0.611111
```